# 18.10, full disk encryption, fresh install freezing after login

Tags: encryption, 18.10

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 with full disk encryption (selected on install) onto a Lenovo T480. After the installation completes and the computer reboots I put in my full disk password, then log into Ubuntu propper.

The first time tutorial pops up then I have just enough time to pull up `terminal -> top` before everything starts lagging then the mouse and keyboard will stop responding.

Top says the `kworker 0` and `kworker 7` are both taking up 100% of the cpu.

I left the computer open overnight (~8 hours) to see if it would sort itself out. Of course the computer went to the lock screen. Now I can't log back in. I can put in the password and press enter, but the password input will go gray and then the screen will go black and I will have to start over putting my password in again.

Is this normal will full disk encryption? Does it normally take a long time to get to a normal state?

Computer: T480, i7, 256gb nvme ssd, 16gb ram.